Python : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ...?
I am trying to run a very simple python project on VScode/Pycharm.
Directory Structure
PythonAnalyticalProject/
├── sales_analysis/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── cli.py
│   ├── constants.py
│   ├── db.py
│   ├── sales_analysis.py   (contains main)
├── images/
│   ├── image1.png/
│   └── image2.png/
├── setup.py
└── requirements.txt

I have installed the requirements.txt dependencies and also added the project directory in PYTHONPATH.
But I am still getting an error when I execute sales_analysis.py.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sales_analysis.cli'; 'sales_analysis' is not a package

This error originated on a line which had an import statement
from sales_analysis.cli import user_continue

How do I solve this error.  I seem to have made all needed configurations, but the error still persists.

You have both a python file and a module folder named sales_analysis.  You intended to import the module, but it found the file first.  Easiest solution is to rename one of them.

And it's not going to FIND the module if the current directory is inside sales_analysis.  You would need to add the parent directory to the Python path.  Either that, or just do import cli.

I'm assuming you didn't write that code but are just trying to run it. If so, you should file a bug ticket so that the code and/or the usage instructions are fixed. If you're writing the code though, extract a [mcve] first.

Short Answer
Rename the sales_analysis folder or the sales_analysis.py file to avoid the naming conflict.
Long Answer
Since you are running sales_analysis.py, it would be more appropriate to replace:
python
from sales_analysis.cli import user_continue

with:
python
from .cli import user_continue

This change is necessary because there is already a folder within the directory. If you run setup.py, there will be no issue with the naming of the folders.
By using the relative import (from .cli import user_continue), you correctly reference the cli module within the same package. This approach ensures compatibility and avoids conflicts with the package naming.
For more information, you can refer to articles on
RealPython

By running the code as python path/to/sales_analysis/sales_analysis.py you are imlicitly adding path/to/PythonAnalyticalProject/sales_analysis/ to PYTHONPATH. When a path is added in this way it will also be the first entry to be checked for modules and package too! This means that import sale_analysis will find PythonAnalyticalProject/sales_analysis/sales_analysis.py in preference to PythonAnalyticalProject/sales_analysis/ as the source for the sales_analysis module/package.
To avoid adding path/to/PythonAnalyticalProject/sales_analysis/ to PYTHONPATH run the code as:
python -m sales_analysis.sales_analysis


There are three ways to solve this:

Change the name of the directory sales_analysis to some other name. Remember, do not change your sales_analysis.py python file's name.

Change your import statement to import using the dot notation:
from .cli import user_continue

Alternatively, you can change the import statement to a full path import, like this:
from PythonAnalyticalProject.sales_analysis.cli import user_continue


